# error while making many2many relationship in Flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, orm, relational-database

I need to make database in such way:

- user
  –– id
  –– mail
  –– password
  –– orders (orders, relation)
- dish
  –– id
  –– title
  –– price
  –– description
  –– picture
  –– category (relation)
- categories
  –– id
  –– title
  –– dishes (meals, attitude)
- orders
  –– id
  -- the date
  –– amount
  –– status
  -- post office
  -- telephone
  -- the address
  –– a list of dishes in the order ( many2many)

I use such code:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    mail = db.Column(db.String)
    password = db.Column(db.String)
    orders = db.relationship("Order", back_populates='user')


####!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!#########
association_table = db.Table('association',
                             db.Column('meal_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('meals.id')),
                             db.Column('order_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('orders.id'))
                             )

class Order(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'orders'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = db.Column(db.String)
    summ = db.Column(db.Float)
    status = db.Column(db.String)
    mail = db.Column(db.String)
    phone = db.Column(db.String)
    adresses = db.Column(db.String)
    user = db.relationship("User")
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    meals = db.relationship(
        "Meals", secondary=association_table, back_populates="meals"
    )

    ####    –– список блюд в заказе(можно через запятую, можно many2many)

class Meals(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'meals'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String)
    description = db.Column(db.String)
    picture = db.Column(db.String)
    category = db.relationship("Category")
    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category.id'))
    orders = db.relationship(
        "Order", secondary=association_table, back_populates="orders"
    )



class Category(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'categories'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String)
    meals = db.relationship("Meals", back_populates='category')
```

and I get an error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'meals.category_id' could not find table 'category' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'
```

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: maybe try lowercasing `Category` in line `category = db.relationship("Category")`?

Comment: Foreign keys reference the tablename, not the class name. So you should write "db.ForeignKey('categories.id').

Comment: thannk you,it solved the problem!!